# Using a "RewriteRule" instead of RedirectMatch for website old urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have recently migrate my database to a new CMS version from v 1.6.7 to v 2.7 (php melody).

so after that i noticed urls indexed in google and other search engines using the old url structure are considered as 404 not found:
Old Url structure:
    BaseUrl/artist_name/video_title_videoID.html

The new url structure got rid of Artist_name field:

```
BaseUrl/video_title_videoID.html
```

I used :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[\w-]+/([\w-]+\.html)$ /$1
```

This rule  redirects urls but not helping indexing those pages even users will found the pages and not 404...
So am looking for "RewriteRule" instead of  RedirectMatch for those old urls...

The htaccess rules used to rewrite videos is:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)_([a-zA-Z0-9]{9}).html$ watch.php?vid=$2
```

Thank you for your valuable time!

Comment: If this `RedirectMatch` works, then don't change it. Indexing a website takes quite some time. It could take several weeks until your whole website is reindexed, so you need a lot of patience.

Comment: but in webmasters tools they putting about 10000 of those urls with status 404 and submitting to index must be done manually ! and it will take weeks to submit manually with google spam forms! I just need to add something that will add the /...../  to the rewrite rule i provided above. the problem that i don't know if it's possible to rewrite the      ^([^/]*)_([a-zA-Z0-9]{9}).html

Comment: Doing it with `RewriteRule` instead of `RedirectMatch` doesn't speed up the reindexing process.

Comment: but would google read pages as regular ones or it will see it always 404 not found this is the difference...?

Comment: Google sees whatever your web server delivers. It doesn't care and doesn't know how the server gets there. If the server sends a redirect, it follows this redirect, that's it. This is why I said, if it works, leave it as it is, and be patient.